# How to create a output log window similar to visual studio log window

Tags: c#, winforms, logging, visual-studio-2017

I need to add an output window to my windows form, similar to the output window in visual studio. [image]

What i have done is created a list box and planning to log the details as and when they arrive. I dont know how to add the highlighted button controls (close, windows position, autohide). I am completely new to visual studio, winforms, c#. Just exploring various things to draft an application. I would be nice if anyone could suggest ideas in adding those controls.

And also please suggest if there is an alternative to list box to display the output window.

Comment: It's a DockPanel

Comment: There is no dockpanel component in winforms. How to add it?

Comment: You can create a panel,add a list box to it ,add some buttons or pictureboxes for the closing and hiding events, Then in the close and hide buttons, use `Panl.Visible = False`

Comment: its a good idea, but  is there any custom way of doing it, instead of adding buttons or picture boxes, like a template kind of thing?

Comment: http://dockpanelsuite.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Sam W 's comment, Using DockPanel would create a another window inside the winform, similar to output, error window in Visual Studio IDE.

[dockpanelsuite.com](https://dockpanelsuite.com)

This site provides amazing Docking Features  http://docs.dockpanelsuite.com/ provides steps to install them.

In Form 1, set **isMidiContainer = true** in Form1's Properties and drag the DockPanel from toolBox(after installing and following steps in that page).

create a form2 and add the following

```
using WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking;

namespace Forms
{
  public partial class Form2 : DockContent
  {
     public Form2()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
 }
}
```

In Form1 add

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Form2 f2 = new Form2();
  f2.Show(dockPanel, DockState.DockBottom);
}
```

We can add many more forms and dock them to one parent form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SplitContainer and add Textbox or RichTextbox as output window you want. You can then append output text to the text property of Textbox ot RichTextbox. Instead of highlighted controls, you can change the size of SplitContainer at run time, or hide one of the section using menu option.

~Nilesh